# Request Administrator Access in Batch File on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, uac

I'm alway using the following code for automatically prompting UAC.It works fine on Windows Vista/7/2008.But it seems that on Windows 8 the script can't get the administrator privilege even the UAC prompts and I click yes.Anything changed?

```
:: Get Administrator Privilege on Windows Vista/7/2008
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
IF '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    ECHO Requesting administrative privileges...
    GOTO UACPrompt
) ELSE ( GOTO gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is nothing to do with the administrator privilege.The problem is about the **default System PATH variables** on some of my Windows 8 machines.C:\windows\system32 is not included in the system path,so all the administration cmds can't be executed unless the currenty directory is C:\Windows\system32.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>net stop wuauserv
The Windows Update service is stopping.
The Windows Update service was stopped successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>cd %userprofile%

C:\Users\itadmin>net start wuauserv
'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\itadmin>set PATH
Path=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\BIN;C:\Program Files\jre1.7.0_21;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

C:\Users\itadmin>
```

As a solution , I added the following line into the batch:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\
```